# Animation project renders in pink?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, color

so im new to blender and just have a small problem. in the 3d view my animation looks like this [image]

Then When I render it it turns purple like this [image]

Anyway I can get it to render normaly so the pokeballs and writing isnt purple?

Comment: You don't have the right path to your image textures, resulting in them not showing up, resulting in a pink filler replacing them.

Comment: And how do I get the right paths? literally just started using this today lol.

Comment: See my answer below. If there is any more help you need, let me know. Conversely, if my answer helps you, please consider accepting it by selecting the checkmark in its upper, left-hand corner. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!

Answer (score 1):

All *External Data* i.e. images, scripts, *VSE Strips*, etc. are found and utilized through a *Path*. A *Path* may look something like the following, which would use *Image.png* and find it on my *Desktop*.

`/Users/ShadyPuck/Desktop/Image.png`

If the *Path* leads to a directory that doesn't exist or attempts to use an *Image Name* that isn't in that directory (in other words, it can't find the file), Blender will return pink.

What you need to do is locate the correct files for each pink instance in Blender's *File Browser* window.

Comment: So im using a template from youtube, so I basically have to have those images on my computer? Meaning i cant use the template?

Comment: @Saul Meaning you either need to contact the YouTuber and ask for them, ask for a .blend with the images _Packed_, or create your own images. Many users on this site have had a wide range of problems with YouTube intros, so I might suggest following some tutorials and creating your own (much more reliable). I might start with tutor4u; he has fantastic beginner tutorials.

Comment: Ok I do have a .blend file how do you know if there are packed images??

Comment: @Saul If they aren't pink.